# Not able to get my page's fan's information

Tags: jakarta-ee, facebook-graph-api

I am doing a POC, I created a Facebook Apps and under that i created a Page, I need to access the information(favourite team,players, books, interests) of user's who have given like's to the page, Currently i am able to get likes count and messages posted information not fan's information like name,favourite team,players, books, interests etc..

Answer (score 0):

To get that information via the Graph API, you need to have the user authenticate your application with the permissions required to get at each of the data points.  Please read http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ and for a list of permissions you need to request from the user, please read: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes i have read the above link, i have created the access token and with above peromissions, able to get Page's fan count and Messages posted information not Fan's information..Just to clarify i need to get the fan's information of the facebook Page which i have created under the Facebook App's not Facebook Apps. This is my Facebook Page Id:185652801533733..

Comment: This is the important part of my answer: "**you need to have the user authenticate your application**".

Comment: Once again thanks for the reply, when u mean by "you need to have the user authenticate your application" no one using a application here only my facebook page "185652801533733" has been accessed by my fan's not any Apps, so how do i get fan's information who access my facebook page(185652801533733)

Comment: That's up to you on how, when and where you authenticate a user.  See the two links I gave in my answer above.